# scala - Find a pair in a list only with first element value

Tags: scala, list, dictionary

Suppose that we have a list like: `val list = List((1,'o'), (3,'t'), (10, 't'), (7, 's'))`.

Then I want to find a pair whose first element is `10`, ignoring what the second element is.

How can I find the pair or the index of the pair?

I tried `list.indexOf((10,_))`, `list.indexOf((10,???))` and so on. However,
as you know, these tries are wrong.

Any suggestions are welcome :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `indexWhere` to find the index:

```
list.indexWhere(_._1 == 10)
```

If you want the pair you can use `find`:

```
list.find(_._1 == 10)
```

Note that `find` returns an option because it may not find any element. If you want to return a default value you can use `getOrElse`, otherwise you need to handle the not found case:

```
list.find(_._1 == 10).getOrElse(/* default value */)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This is what I want.